# How do i get a graphics object in Java?

Tags: java

Im making a basic space invaders game. I got all the resources from the LWJGL .zip file (Im not using LWJGL librarys to create my game, just got the pictures, etc. from it.) Anyway, whenever i press "space" on my keyboard, my KeyListener creates a new bullet that my ship fires. However, i dont know how to draw the bullets image, since my KeyListener doesnt pass a graphics object, and you need one to draw a image. The code thats causing the problem is the "drawImage" method in the "Shot" constructor. Heres my code:

```
    public class KeyTyped{

    public void keyESC(){
        Screen.isRunning = false;
    }

    public void keyLEFT() {
        Screen.shipPosX -= 10;

    }

    public void keyRIGHT() {
        Screen.shipPosX += 10;

    }
    //This is automatically called from my KeyListener whenever i 
    //press the spacebar
    public void keySPACE(){
        if(!spacePressed){
            ShotHandler.scheduleNewShot();
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }


}
```

public class ShotHandler {

```
public static int shotX = Screen.shipPosX;
public static int shotY = Screen.shipPosY + 25;




public static void scheduleNewShot() {
    //All this does is set a boolean to 'false', not allowing you to fire any more shots until a second has passed.
    new ShotScheduler(1);


    new Shot(25);
}
```

}

public class Shot extends ShotHandler{

```
public Shot(int par1){

    //This is my own method to draw a image. The first parameter is the graphics object that i need to draw.
    GUI.drawImage(*????????*, "res/spaceinvaders/shot.gif", ShotHandler.shotX, ShotHandler.shotY);

}
            //Dont worry about this, i was just testing something
    for(int i = 0; i <= par1; i++){
        ShotHandler.shotY++;
    }
}
```

}

Thanks guys! Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store the location of the "bullet" somewhere, and then access that state within your `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. Really, this should be factored out quite a bit. Make your `Shot` class look something like this:

```
public class Shot {
    private Point location; // Could be Point2D or whatever class you need

    public Shot(Point initLocation) {
        this.location = initLocation;
    }

    // Add getter and setter for location

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        // put your drawing code here, based on location
    }
 }
```

Then in your key pressed method,

```
public void keySPACE(){
    // Add a new shot to a list or variable somewhere
    // WARNING: You're getting into multithreading territory.
    // You may want to use a synchronized list.
    yourJPanelVar.repaint();
}
```

And you'll extend `JPanel` and override `paintComponent`.

```
public class GameScreen extends JPanel {
    public paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        for (shot : yourListOfShots) {
             shot.draw(g);
        }
        // And draw your ship and whatever else you need
    }
 }
```

That's the basic idea. Hope it makes some sense now. You could move the `Shot`'s drawing code elsewhere, I suppose, but for simplicity, I just stuck on the `Shot` class itself.

I will note that what I have above is some pretty messy code. Look into the MVC pattern. It makes for much cleaner state abstraction (decouples the state from the display code).

Comment: `foreach` doesn't exist in Java, it's just `for`

Comment: @BackSlash Thanks. Been on C# for quite a while.

Answer (score 5):

The idea is that the listeners should change the *state* of the game (i.e. create a bullet, or change the location of the bullet, or whatever), and then call `repaint()`. Then Swing will invoke the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, which will paint the updated game state using the Graphics passed as argument.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I know about the paintComponent(), repaint(), states, etc. , but i just cant seem to put it together. (Sorry, i just started looking at java game tutorials. I knew Java for at least 2 years now, but im not the most...advanced game programmer yet xD.)

Comment: If you are doing some custom painting, try overriding the `paint(Graphics g)` method on your `JPanel` (be sure to call `super.paint(g)`), and put your rendering code in there. You use the `Graphics` object that gets passed in. Then when calling `repaint()`, your custom rendering will be triggered.

Comment: @akf Swing classes recommend not overriding `paint`, as I recall. `paint` contains code that handles the background and the like.

Comment: @akf jpmc26 is right, you should override the `paintComponent` method, not the `paint` method. As for [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html): _For all practical purposes paintComponent will be the only method that you will ever need to override_

Comment: got it - i'd edit my comment if i could - but the poster should get the gist - ..try overriding the *`paintComponent(Graphics g)`* method...